# adding uploader to php script

Tags: php, uploader

Regarding this ...... question but......... still learning :3
so i have a php file lets say called x.php and all working i would like to add uploader so people can upload txt files ....... but i dnt want to have another file which is uploader.php
Thnx in advance......

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
upload ur CV.<br>
<form action="same.php" method="post"><br>
<input type="file" name="uploadFile">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Wordlist">
</form>
</body>
</html>
</center>
<?php
move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadFile'] ['tmp_name'], 
       "../uploads/{$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name']}")
?>
```

Comment: [`enctype="multipart/form-data"`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), it's quite emphasized in the manual.

Comment: can you calrify pls... tu

Comment: It means that this `<form action="same.php" method="post">` should be this `<form action="same.php" method="post "enctype="multipart/form-data">` which is an essential part of uploading files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form lacks `"enctype="multipart/form-data"` in
`<form action="same.php" method="post">` which should read like this
`<form action="same.php" method="post "enctype="multipart/form-data">`

This is an ***essential*** part of uploading files.

Consult the manuals:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php**
- **http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php**

Plus, make sure that the folder is writeable and with proper permissions set.

---

**Edit:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
upload ur CV.<br>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
<input type="file" name="uploadFile">
<input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Upload Wordlist">
</form>
</body>
</html>
</center>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadFile'] ['tmp_name'], 
           "../uploads/{$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name']}");
    }
?>
```

Comment: TU !!! GOT IT ? but now when press upload my whole script runs ... and doesnt upload but no  errors.

Comment: i gave it 777 and tried with 755

Comment: tu for the care i copy pasted it inside my script still doesnt wanna upload :3

Comment: You're doing `../uploads` which translates to, the upload folder is one sub-folder down from where you are executing the code. Do visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php and read through it. @lionTHEWold there's nothing more than I have already said that could be of help; that's about all there is too it.

Comment: TU :) even thought u have changed it to / which is dir but anyway tu :)

Comment: me again, now my upload and submit button do the same just run the script ? even though they r with diffrent names any indea ?